# need sql query to get min and max experience?

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns `(exp_Years, exp_months)`.
Saving years and months in 2 different columns.

Now I need a SQL Query to get min and max experience

```
If minExp=2years and maxExp=4years
```

how do I get records with out getting 4.1 and 4.2 exp?

example data:--

table: Resume(name, email, phone, exp_years, exp_months)
I need list of records with exp_years>2 and exp_years<5... but how to check exp_months here..

if I use exp_years>2 and exp_years< 5 condition am getting records with 5years 1 month, 5year 2 months are also getting.

I need only more than 2 years and less than or equals 5 years 0 months.. but not 5years 1month and moreee....

**actually I need hibernate HQL Query....**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post an example of your data and needed result, the queries you already tried and the problems you had? Besides, are you using mySql or Oracle? Can you please remove the wrong tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange way of storing the data. So you are supposed to store two years and three months as years = 2 and months = 3.

But you could just as well store years = 1 and months = 15 or years = 0 and months = 27, which would be the same time span. This said, it would be better to have just one column, i.e `months` only.

Then to get records with a time span of over 2 years and until 5 years exactly you'd select

```
where months between 25 and 60
```

If you must live with the table design you are showing, then you can always calculate `total months = years * 12 + months`. That would be

```
where years * 12 + months between 25 and 60
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make this by add months to years after divide months on 12 then you can use `ROUND` to round to int value:

```
select ROUND(max(exp_Years+exp_months/12)), ROUND(min(exp_Years+exp_months/12))
from your_table
```